# Pine script strategy take profits points to study plots

Tags: pine-script, trading

How would I convert something like this in a strategy to a study. I solely need to covert this so it can create alert conditions I'm just trying to determine the percent change since the last buy signal alert if you get what I'm saying. So I have one take profit at a percent change from buy signal say 3.1% for example and the other TP is say 10.4% I need to covert these points from a strategy into study plots so I can create alerts. If anyone could be of help that would be great.

if (strategy.position_size>0)
strategy.exit(id="TP", qty_percent=50, limit=longExitPrice)

strategy.exit("AVG TP", qty_percent=easywin, limit=avgExitPrice)